# Unable to convert argument to date format

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

So I have a macro here which takes sas month in yymmn6 format to compute the next 2 months.

```
%macro pull(yymm);
%let month1=%sysfunc(inputn(&yymm.,yymmn6.));
%let month2=%sysfunc(inputn(intnx('month',&month1.,1),yymmn6.));
%let month3=%sysfunc(inputn(intnx('month',&month1.,2),yymmn6.));
%put &month1 &month2 &month3;
%mend;
%pull(201807);
```

I'm not being able to understand the error in the code because I get the following warning:

```
Argument 1 to function INPUTN referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range.
```

When I check the log, &month1 comes as 21366 which should ideally have been 201807. Can somebody please help me out here?

Comment: You are asking the `YYMMN6.` informat to convert the string `INPUTN`.  It is expecting digits instead.

Comment: Hi Tom, I face the same error when I use PUTN as well.

Comment: In addition to what Tom said, it looks like your input date is in the format `yyyymm6`, not `yymmn6`

Comment: The `INTNX()` function does recognize any intervals with quotes in its name.  Remove the quotes around `MONTH`.

Comment: Please show what values your want in the macro variables for your example input.

Comment: Hi Tom, so if 201807 is July'18 then Month2 should be 201808 and Month3 should be 201809

Comment: If you want the values formatted then you need to tell SAS that.  Otherwise it will just return the actual number of days since 1960.  Like `21366 21397 21428`.

Comment: could you show me how please? I don't quite follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function needs its own %SYFUNC() wrapper so your code is passing the literal string `INTNX(` to INPUTN() function.  Also you don't need to add quotes around string values in macro code. So remove the quotes around `MONTH`.

So first convert your YYYYMM string into a date. Then pass that date value to the INTNX() function.  You can use the optional second parameter of the `%SYSFUNC()` function to specify what format to use when converting the function result into a string.

```
%macro pull(yymm);
%local date;
%let date=%sysfunc(inputn(&yymm,yymmn6));
%let month1=%sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,0),yymmn6.);
%let month2=%sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,1),yymmn6.);
%let month3=%sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,2),yymmn6.);
%put &month1 &month2 &month3;
%mend;
%pull(201807);
```

Results:

```
201807 201808 201809
```